# Inputs for Diagonal Difference Algorithm are not correct for values outside the bounds specified in the code

Tags: c++, algorithm, matrix

The inputs for the two-dimensional vector matrix is first an input that asks for the size of the matrix, which works fine. But part of the requirement for the code is that the values in the matrix have to be between -100 and 100, but the buffer I set up for keeping values within that range cause the matrix to get out of order when the line is re-entered.

I don't really know the source of the issue, so I don't know what to try. The furthest I got was determining the root of the problem to be that when line is re-entered after being buffered, the line ends up out of order in the final matrix, which I determined by visualizing the matrix after all the values were assigned.

```
/**Matrix Input**/
int main(){
    cout << "Enter size of matrix: ";
    int n = 0;
    cin >> n;
    cout << endl;
    vector<vector<int> > arr (n, vector<int>(n));
    cout << "Enter Format: \na b c[en.]\nd e f[en.]\ng h i[en.]" << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        cout << "Enter Line " << i + 1 << endl;
        for (int r = 0; r < n; r++){
            cin >> arr[r][i];
            /**Root of Error: Out of Specified Range**/
            if (arr[r][i] > 100){
                cout << endl;
                cout << "Error: Value " << r + 1 << " is over 100. Please re-enter line" << endl;
                i--;
                break;
            }
            if (arr[r][i] < -100){
                cout << endl;
                cout << "Error: Value " << r + 1 << " is less than -100. Please re-enter line" << endl;
                i--;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    /* Printing out the Matrix */
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        for (int r = 0; r < n; r++){
            cout << arr[r][i] << " ";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
    return 0; 
}
```

The matrix is generated fine when all the values are in range. For example, say I enter the lines {1 2 3}, {4 5 6}, and {7 8 9}. The matrix it outputs is correct. But say for the second line I incorrectly entered {4 500 6}, then proceed to correct it to {4 5 6}. I expected it would generate the same matrix as the one shown in the first lines of example, but instead it generated {{1 2 3}, {6 4 5}, {6 7 8}}. And this is true for any case where one or more of the lines has to be re-entered.

I do not know the source of this problem, so help would be appreciated.

Comment: Ignore the rest of the bad line with `std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n')`.

Comment: Please, [stop](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/57762972/revisions) to add "solved" in the answer's title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that when you enter

```
4 500 6
```

500 triggers the error and gets out of the loop, but `6` is still there waiting to be read. your next `i` iteration will find

```
6 <enter> 4 5 6
```

so the line will be 6 4 5 and the '6' will remain for next line that will be

```
6 <enter> 7 8
```

Your final `9` will never be processed by the program.

If you want to work by lines then you need to read strings (with `getline`) and split them into fields yourself.

Comment: Thanks for the response. This indeed was the problem, and using cin.ignore, as recommended by Alexander Zhang in the comments, I was able to solve the problem.